# How do you pass email body dynamiclly to MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hello all and thanks for your time.  I believe I have a simple question.

I am trying to strip the string email body of it's quote marks (they seem to come from getting the getting my body from a dictionary) and pass it to MailObject....with no luck I keep getting SIGBRT on my *finalString line.
What am I missing.  Thanks again for any help.

```
NSMutableDictionary *my_data = [myMasterOrderList objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row];
   NSMutableArray   *toEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [toEmail addObject:[my_data objectForKey:@"repemail"]];

   NSMutableString *toBody = [my_data objectForKey:@"myOrder"];
  // [toBody addObject:[my_data objectForKey:@"myOrder"]];
  // NSString *finalSting = [[NSString alloc] init];
   NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[toBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%20"]];

   NSLog(@" toBody my_data%@", finalString);
//*************  SEND MAIL *************
   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

       MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
       [mailViewController setToRecipients:toEmail];
       [mailViewController setSubject:@"Sub Goes Here."];
       [mailViewController setMessageBody:finalString isHTML:NO];

       [self presentModalViewController:mailViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code:

```
NSString *toBody = @"this \" is my \" body \" email\"";
NSMutableString *finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[toBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%20"]];
NSLog(@"%@", finalString);
```

The output of the NSLog is:

```
2012-05-07 19:44:04.157 StringTesting[19203:f803] this %20 is my %20 body %20 email%20
```

I actually copied your code to use. I know it sounds basic, but since mine worked, have you tried restarting Xcode and/or rebooting your machine, cleaning your project, etc...?

Comment: Yes to Cleaning the project but NO to all else.  will try now.  Thx.

Comment: Just bounced the machine to no avail.  Thanks anyway at least I'm not totally crazy.

Comment: I tried your code in the same project and it worked perfect. Apparently - NSMutableArray   *toEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; - Is not really a string ????????? it still thinks it's an Array....am I doing something wrong when I pull from my Dictionary ??????? Totally Lost !!!

Comment: In your comment, you wrote `NSMutableArray *toEmail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`. Unless that's a typo, of course it's not an `NSString` (it's an `NSMutableArray`). If it *is* a typo, post your actual code and I'll look at it.

Comment: Wow, so sorry typo on my part what I actually have is.....  NSMutableString *toBody = [my_data objectForKey:@"myOrder"];....   for my body section

Comment: So, how is `my_data` stored/generated? Where do you get it? Why do you think it's an `NSString`? If you set a breakpoint right after the line where you assign/create it, in the inspector at the bottom of the screen, what kind of object is it listed as?

Comment: my_data is coming from the tableView Array which is in-turn coming from an array of Dictionaries from my .plist. Hope that helps and thx for the effort. (Atleast that's what I think it does as my code is written in original post).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that train, but if it is an `NSArray` that was in an `NSDictionary`, at what point do you think it turns into an `NSString`? Is the array made up of `NSString` objects?

Comment: I was under the impression that in obj-c declaring the variable type is what determines the type (e.g. NSString *newString = [some other datatype....].  I am novice so this may be a bad assumption on my part.  How would I cast an Array to a string ???

Comment: It is what it is stored as. `NSArray != NSString`. You've got to determine how to convert it. If it's an array of numbers, how would it automatically know what you want the string to look like? You might iterate over the items and add them to an `NSMutableString`, separating each value by a comma or do something else entirely. The language/compiler can't know what you want; you have to specify it yourself. Why don't you write another question asking about that?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is this: `withString:@"%20"` it needs to be `withString:@"%%20"` Since the % character is special in NSStrings, to have a literal % sign, you need to escape it.

I would also note that if you don't need finalString to be mutable (from the code you have posted, you don't), you can just do this:

```
NSString *finalString = [toBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"%%20"];
```

Comment: I used his code as-is and it worked. I'm not sure it ***has*** to be `@"%%20"`.

Comment: Just tried your new way...sorry to say same result.  Thanks anyway

Comment: not sure if this helps but this is the error in the console  2012-05-07 16:20:55.655 AllRewards[352:207] -[__NSCFArray stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62d7c40
2012-05-07 16:20:55.661 AllRewards[352:207] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x62d7c40'

Comment: That means that `toBody` is an array, not a string.